# How to only execute a function once in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ethers.js

I have an *if else* statement in my main function, when the *if* statement is true I want to continue another function inside the *if* statement.

However the *if* statement stays true until a transaction is confirmed, which leads to retrigger the 2nd function to be executed more than once.

The `buyToken` function gets executed inside the *if* statement of the `mempool` function

```
   async function buyToken(){
      try{
      const value = '1000000000000000'
      const amountOut = await routerContract.getAmountsOut(value,[wbnb, tokenToFrontRun] )
      console.log(ethers.utils.formatEther(amountOut[0]))
      console.log(ethers.utils.formatUnits(amountOut[1], 9))
      
        const buy = await routerContract.swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
          0,
          [wbnb, tokenToFrontRun],
          address,
          Date.now() + 1000 *60*3,
          {
              'value':value,
              'gasPrice':ethers.utils.parseUnits('80', 'gwei'),
              'gasLimit':300000
          }
      )
          receipt = await buy.wait()
          console.log(receipt.transactionHash)
          return
    
    
        }catch(e){
          console.log(e)
        }
      }
    
        
     
    
    async function mempool(){
        provider.on("pending", async(tx)=>{
            const txInfo = await provider.getTransaction(tx);
            
            try{
              //console.log(txInfo.to)
              if(toChecksumAddress(txInfo.to) == routerAddress){
                console.log("to uniswap router")
                const iface = new ethers.utils.Interface(routerAbi);
                let decodedData = iface.parseTransaction({ data: txInfo.data});
                const valueSent = ethers.utils.formatUnits(txInfo.value, 'ether')
                const first = decodedData.args.path[0]
                const lastItem = decodedData.args.path
                const last = lastItem[lastItem.length -1]
                if(toChecksumAddress(first) == wbnb && toChecksumAddress(last) == tokenToFrontRun ){
                    console.log(txInfo);
                    console.log(ethers.utils.formatEther(txInfo.value))
                    console.log(ethers.utils.formatUnits(txInfo.gasPrice, 'gwei'))
                   // console.log(ethers.utils.formatUnits(txInfo.gasLimit, 'gwei'))
                    console.log(txInfo.confirmations)
                    console.log(txInfo.from)
                    
    
                    console.log("front running transaction")
                    await buyToken()
                      
                      
                }
                
              }
                
            }
            catch (e){
              //console.log("no data to show");
              //console.log(e)
            }
            
        })
    }
    
    
    mempool()
```

So how can I make it so that the `buyToken` function is only executed once?

I know there are plenty of [tutorials on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_break.asp#:%7E:text=The%20break%20statement%20breaks%20out,the%20loop%20(if%20any)), but this doesn't really help me in this case.

Comment: Do you just want that the event gets triggered once?

Comment: they buyToken fucntion should only get triggered once. if the if staement turns true, it will stay true until its noot true, which can be a few seconds, but during the time the buyToken fucntion gets retriggered and i only want to execute it once, nomatter how long the if statement is true

Answer (score 0):

Define the `buyToken` function as an arrow function.

```
let buyToken = async () => {
   // your logic
}
```

Then in the event,

```
if (buyToken)
   await buyToken();
buyToken = null;
```

But, in ethers.js instead of using `on`, you can use `once` to call the method once.
So, in your case,

```
provider.once("pending", async(tx)=>{
   // your logic
})
```

Comment: ok i will try this, but a question to ethers once, will this only check once for pending trasnactions?

Comment: It will listen to the `pending` event and after a pending transaction is added, the function will be called. It will not be called again anymore.
It works similarly to a DOM event. e.g.-
`document.body.addEventListener("scroll", (ev) => {}, { once: true });`

Comment: what you mean it will listen to pending event once? Im trying to scan pmempool aslong until my if() statement becomes true, after that it should only execute function once.

Comment: do you know more about ethers? I also want to know why sometimes the buy fucntion isnt executed at all? do you have a few minutes to chat somewhere?

Comment: also the whole thing you posted isnt working, it keeps reexecuting the buy function